# Button_to : update database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an object A which is linked to many ojbects B (has_many / belongs_to)
In "Show" view of object A, I would like to have a button which, when a user click on it, change the status of all objects B linked to it and just refresh the page.

I checked and it seems that I need to use button_to with remote => true but I really don't understand how it is supposed to works.

Is it the good option ?

Comment: Can you share a bit more detail and code please?

Comment: My object A has some objects B attached by has_many/belongs_to relation. B objects have a state (an integer, 0 or 1). I would like to change this state for all of B objects by clicking on a single button when I am on the "show" page of my object A. Is this clear enough ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to refresh the page after it, you can just point this button to some action at your controller and then `redirect_to :back`. :remote => true causes the page to send an AJAX request and it will not reload the page.

Comment: Or just don't set `:remote => true`, if the page is going to refresh anyway.

Comment: yes, but how do I use button_to to update objects B (juste change an integer) ?

Comment: Well the button will just get you started, you'll need to set up the routing, a controller action, etc. The button just gets the party started, and `button_to` is just a view helper that renders some html for you.